# Are vector<list<int> > and list<vector<int> > same And when we declare these then how they remain in memory?

Tags: c++, stl

I have seen a video tutorial where they used `vector<list<int> >` to implement BFS algorithm. But I did not understand this at all and I am getting confused to distinguish `vector<list<int> >` and `list<vector<int> >`. I have tried to draw a schematic memory representation to understand how they remain in memory, but could not.

Comment: Why do you need to worry about how they are laid out in memory?    As far as your code is concerned, for the most part, it is the operations you can do which matter, not the internal organisation.   Would you worry about the difference between a box full of plastic bags, and a plastic bag full of boxes?    Or would you simply work out how to use whichever one you've got?

Comment: @Peter I don't fully agree. We are speaking about C++, which people use in places where program speed is important. Memory organization can affect program speed, so I think the question is valid. It isn't only about what data structures can do, but how fast will they do.

Comment: @MBI - The OP has given no reason for the concern and I asked why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They differ pretty much, `std::vector` resides in continuous block of memory, on the contrary every item of `std::list` can be located anywhere in memory. **To choose the right structure, you need to know what kind of the operation you wanna do with the data (read/change/add) and how often**.

For example it's easy to find something in vector if you know index of the item, but nothing like index works in list. When you search in list, you jump from one item to the other, until you find the item you are looking for. In list the item knows only it's right and left neighbor.

It isn't so simple as I describe, list has it's pros also. For example adding item to list is always allocating memory for just one item, but if vector is on it's memory limit, you need to allocate memory for the whole new vector, and copy all old vector data there. But when vector isn't on it's limit, you don't have to allocate any memory, and the operation is super fast. All memory allocations are slowing down the process.

So in summary : **Every data structure has it's pros and cons, it really depends what you need it for.**

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to draw a schematic memory representation

You don't have to.

Your code should be concerned about the methods each data structure offers.

> Are `vector<list<int>>` and `list<vector<int>>` same?

No.

The most important difference is that the vector's elements lie in contiguous memory blocks, while the list's aren't required to respect this principle.